# Как узнать, что я вернулся на страницу назад?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

Пользователь перешёл методом `Frame.Navigate` на из `MainPage` в `SomePage`, а потом нажал кнопку "Back". Как мне узнать на `MainPage`, что пользователь вернулся на неё кнопкой "Back", а не запустил сначала приложение?

Comment: Уточните, почему это принципиально? Перерисовывать окно вполне возможно что надо, кто его знает, что случилось, пока пользователь был на SomePage.

Comment: @Monk При первом запуске окна, я загружаю некоторые данные из интернета, и заношу их в бд. Мне нужно что бы когда я вернулся назад, данные просто взялись из бд, а не грузились заново. Я конечно могу создать статическую переменную bool которую буду менять в ходе перемещений по программе, но неужели нету никаких иных способов?

Comment: Данные с интернета загружайте в базу в событии Initialized, отрисовку и чтение базы - в Loaded, тогда загрузка будет одноразовой, а чтение из базы - регулярным. Загрузка в initialized на самом деле тоже некрасиво, но в любом случае, так или иначе делаете загрузку одноразовой. Только при пустой базе данных, только при инициализации, только пока отдельная переменная false. Как угодно.

Comment: @Monk спасибо большое. Вы оформите это как ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У страницы есть `overload` метод `OnNavigatedTo` в параметрах которого есть сведения и типе навигации: класс `NavigationEventArgs` с перечислением `NavigationMode`

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
       // your code here
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Данные с интернета загружайте в базу в событии `Initialized`, отрисовку и чтение базы - в `Loaded`, тогда загрузка будет одноразовой, а чтение из базы - регулярным. Ну и, за компанию - выгрузку больших объемов данных например можно делать на `Unloaded`.

Загрузка в `Initialized` на самом деле тоже некрасивое решение, но в любом случае, так или иначе делаете загрузку одноразовой. Условие уже на ваше усмотрение - только при пустой базе данных, только при инициализации, только пока отдельная переменная `false`. Как угодно.